# How to find all cells on the sheet with a certain word and place them in another column?

Tags: google-sheets

Using this regex

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A2,$B$1)
```

I can match all cells in the column. But how to create a list of matches? For example, take this sheet:
[image]
and create a column of cells which are containing word boho:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have too many columns you can try something like this:

```
=filter({A2:A; B2:B; C2:C}, regexmatch({A2:A; B2:B; C2:C}, "boho"))
```

or, depending on your locale

```
=filter({A2:A; B2:B; C2:C}; regexmatch({A2:A; B2:B; C2:C}; "boho"))
```

Change ranges to suit and see if that helps. If "boho" is in cell B1 you can replace the string with the cell reference.

If you want to check all columns, try

```
=ArrayFormula(substitute(transpose(split(join(,query(if(regexmatch('Sheet1'!A2:5, "boho"), substitute('Sheet1'!A2:5, " ", "¬"),),,rows('Sheet1'!A2:A))), " ")), "¬"," "))
```

Note that there is 50000 character limit on join().

Comment: thank you. Could you explain what do you mean by "locale"? Both lines work the same. Is it possible to make it work for all columns in Sheet1 and place results on Sheet2?

Comment: Some european locales (Netherlands, Denmark, etc..) require the use of a semicolon (instead of a comma) as an argument separator in formulae.

Comment: Update my answer to reference more columns but mind the inherent limitation of join().

Comment: Now I understand, thank you very much. The third line shows nothing.

Comment: How this thing works when the input is a range? `regexmatch({A2:A}; "boho")` I found that it returns only one value (only one cell is true or false).

Comment: You'll have to wrap that in arrayformula(). So: Arrayformula ( regexmatch( A2:A; "boho")). This will return boolean values for the whole range.